# How to install Olson database?

Tags: r, docker, rstudio, jupyter

Attempting to read a csv using read_csv function :

```
library(readr)
read_csv("myfile.csv")
```

returns warning :

```
Warning message in OlsonNames():
“no Olson database found”
```

and then error :

```
Error: Unknown TZ UTC
Traceback:

1. read_csv("myfile.csv")
2. read_delimited(file, tokenizer, col_names = col_names, col_types = col_types, 
 .     locale = locale, skip = skip, comment = comment, n_max = n_max, 
 .     guess_max = guess_max, progress = progress)
3. col_spec_standardise(data, skip = skip, comment = comment, guess_max = guess_max, 
 .     col_names = col_names, col_types = col_types, tokenizer = tokenizer, 
 .     locale = locale)
4. guess_header(ds_header, tokenizer, locale)
5. guess_header_(datasource, tokenizer, locale)
6. default_locale()
7. locale()
8. check_tz(tz)
9. stop("Unknown TZ ", x, call. = FALSE)
```

I do not receive this error in not returned in R studio so assume Olson database is pre installed with R studio ?

How can i install Olson database on R Jupyter notebook in order that `read_csv` will run as expected?

Update :

I receive same error invoking using `OlsonNames()` independently on Jupyter notebook. Jupyter notebook I'm running is container specified at https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/tree/master/r-notebook

Update 2 :

R packages as specified by docker file :

```
# R packages
RUN conda install --quiet --yes \
    'r-base=3.3.2' \
    'r-irkernel=0.7*' \
    'r-plyr=1.8*' \
    'r-devtools=1.12*' \
    'r-tidyverse=1.0*' \
    'r-shiny=0.14*' \
    'r-rmarkdown=1.2*' \
    'r-forecast=7.3*' \
    'r-rsqlite=1.1*' \
    'r-reshape2=1.4*' \
    'r-nycflights13=0.2*' \
    'r-caret=6.0*' \
    'r-rcurl=1.95*' \
    'r-crayon=1.3*' \
    'r-randomforest=4.6*' && \
    conda clean -tipsy && \
    fix-permissions $CONDA_DIR
```

OS : Ubuntu Core 14.04

R Version :

```
jovyan@6cf5af1246ff:~$ R -- version
WARNING: unknown option '--'

ARGUMENT 'version' __ignored__


R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31) -- "Sincere Pumpkin Patch"
Copyright (C) 2016 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

[Previously saved workspace restored]

>
```

Comment: Do you get this when you simply run `OlsonNames()`? This is a base R function and if that fails then its nothing to do with `readr` or possibly RStudio (unless RStudio has broken the R setup...)

Comment: @Spacedman Please see update, appears I'll need to update  docker container this Jupyter notebook is based on.

Comment: Where does `OlsonNexecutinames()` come from? Also, give versions of R, operating system, and packages.

Comment: @Spacedman apologies , OlsonNexecutinames()  should be OlsonNames() , please see question update 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `OlsonNames` function is pretty simple.  In 3.3.2 it looks for the timezone names in these locations:

```
     tzdirs <- c(Sys.getenv("TZDIR"), file.path(R.home("share"), 
        "zoneinfo"), "/usr/share/zoneinfo", "/usr/share/lib/zoneinfo", 
        "/usr/lib/zoneinfo", "/usr/local/etc/zoneinfo", "/etc/zoneinfo", 
        "/usr/etc/zoneinfo")
```

You need to make sure one of the listed directories is available.  If none of the hardcoded ones are on your system, set `TZDIR` to point to a copy.